# Fair play streaming certificate error in apple developer account

Tags: ios, certificate, streaming, fairplay

I am trying to create a FPS (Fair play streaming)certificate but I am getting this error when I upload CSR file which I create by keychain access of mac system

[image]

These are some screenshots of creating CSR file using keychain access.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am not able to understand what is the solution of this error ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the instructions you have received in `<FPS_Credential_Creation_Guide.pdf>` as part of the Deployment package to generate certificate signed request (CSR). Then upload this file as CSR file.

**OpenSSL**

Apple provides the OpenSSL application on macOS. Use openssl from the command line to generate the public/private key pair, certificate signed request (CSR).

1. Generate key pair

   ```
   openssl genrsa -aes256 -out privatekey.pem 1024
   ```
2. Generate CSR

   ```
   openssl req -new -sha1 -key privatekey.pem -out certreq.csr \
       -subj "/CN=SubjectName/OU=OrganizationalUnit/O=Organization/C=US"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In you screenshots you are choosing 2048 RSA, but the error message states 1024 RSA is expected.  Did you try generating a key using 1024?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates, the Certificate Signing Request requires the RSA-2048 algorithm. As an alternative, you can use openSSL to generate the CSR via the following steps:

1. Execute the following openSSL command to create a private key:

`openssl genrsa -out privateKey.key 2048`

2. Execute the following openSSL command to generate a certificate signing request (CSR) from the private key:

`openssl req -new -key privateKey.key -out certificateSigningRequest.csr`